# Heroku push of Rails4 Postgres App failed to compile Ruby app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

This app was generated using Rails Composer and no mods have been made as of yet.  It's the first app where I used Postgres as I used MySQL before.  When I tried to run it locally, it initially failed because PG was listening to port 5433 and the app was trying to connect to port 5432.  I changed PG to listen to 5432 not 5433.  At that point, it began to work.  Locally, I can sign up, login and list users.  That's about all it does right now as I have not modified the original code.

When I:

```
git push heroku master
```

it works until I get these messages:

```
Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
Running: rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
... trace dump ...
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:afternoon-spire-5707.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:afternoon-spire-5707.git'
```

rake assets:precompile works locally:

```
D:\BitNami\rubystack-2.0.0-11\projects\keyandcar>rake assets:precompile
I, [2014-03-01T01:06:01.849873 #28852]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/keyandcar/public/assets
/application-2523f7871b800324a0dde9f6d33ef208.js
I, [2014-03-01T01:06:01.919922 #28852]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/keyandcar/public/assets
/application-5d552226c05f29080fc1703e860817a5.css
I, [2014-03-01T01:06:01.936932 #28852]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/keyandcar/public/assets
/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-171c97066e4db52896df4e14c2905e8e.eot
I, [2014-03-01T01:06:01.949941 #28852]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/keyandcar/public/assets
/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-e327cd5918c69ba34cb1c92b9c7c424a.svg
I, [2014-03-01T01:06:01.981961 #28852]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/keyandcar/public/assets
/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-7206a6a5553d1b106dc988b6af7e29df.ttf
I, [2014-03-01T01:06:01.994971 #28852]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/keyandcar/public/assets
/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-a6d95d67a6db3f50ff64b2103e8c9348.woff
```

I added this to config/application.rb with no effect:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false # for Heroku
```

I'm not sure where the failure is, as to whether it is a precompile problem or PG listening to 5433 instead of 5432 or what.

Thanks for the help...R_G

Comment: What does your gemfile look like? This might be a clue to the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the `rails_12factor` gem in your gemfile as stated [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4)?

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

Comment: You know, I remember seeing that last night and planning to try it but then didn't...  I guess I was tired.  Either way, the push to heroku worked with this fix.  The application still crashed but that was a different problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$ rm Gemfile.lock && bundle
$ git add Gemfile.lock
$ git commit -m "Update Gemfile.lock"
$ git push
```

Comment: this can potentially cause a lot more problems than it solves.

Comment: because you've just said 'ok forget that you built your app against these particular versions of the gems in your Gemfile, and determine an entirely new set of versions, which may or may not be compatible with your app'.

Comment: This is a matter of how the dependencies are declared in the Gemfile. I don't think removing the `Gemfile.lock` is a bad practice. If this caused you problems, it means you are doing it wrong in the Gemfile.

Comment: I agree, it's always a good practice to set the version used for each gem in your gemfile, it's a good way to prevent future head scratches. In this case, removing the gemfile.lock is not an issue.